# How to find "the" definition point of a Value in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, static-analysis, llvm-ir

LLVM uses static single assignment (SSA) form for its IR, meaning that every `Value` has a single definition point. So what is the easiest (and most generic) way to find "the" definition point of a `Value` without having to examine each use and determine how our `Value` is being used? In the code below, I am interested in definition points of `Value`s used as function arguments.

```
protected: void getValueDefs( Function * F ) {
    for (inst_iterator I = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); I != E; ++I) {
      ImmutableCallSite CS( cast<Value>(I) );
      if ( !CS || isa<IntrinsicInst>(I) ) continue;
      for ( User::const_op_iterator Ab = CS.arg_begin(), Ae = CS.arg_end(); Ab != Ae; ++Ab ) {
          for ( User *U : Ab->get()->users() ) {
              if (Instruction *Inst = dyn_cast<Instruction>(U)) {
                  /* How to do the check here?? */
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit of an odd way to write it. I'd probably do something like this:

```
void scanFunc(Function &F) {

  for (Function::iterator BB = F.begin(), E = F.end(); BB != E; ++BB) {
    for (BasicBlock::iterator BBI = BB->begin(), BBE = BB->end(); BBI != BBE;
         ++BBI) {
      if (CallInst *CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(BBI)) {
        dbgs() << "Call: ";
        CI->dump();
        dbgs() << "\n";
        ImmutableCallSite CS(CI);
        for (ImmutableCallSite::arg_iterator I = CS.arg_begin(),
                                             E = CS.arg_end();
             I != E; ++I) {
          if (Instruction *Inst = dyn_cast<Instruction>(*I)) {
            // Do stuff                                                                                                                                                   
            dbgs() << "\tInst: ";
            Inst->dump();
            dbgs() << "\n";

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically though, if it is an instruction, it is the definition of the value. That's how the IR works. Otherwise, it might be a constant etc. If you take this code:

```
int a (int b) {
  return b + 4;
}

int b (int c) {
  return a(c) + a(c-1);
}

int d (int e, int f, int g) {
  int h = a(4);
  int i = b(5);
  int j = b(6);

  return h + i + j + e + f + g;
}
```

and compile it to IR and run this code on it you'll see:

```
Call:   %call = call i32 @_Z1ai(i32 %0)

    Inst:   %0 = load i32* %c.addr, align 4

Call:   %call1 = call i32 @_Z1ai(i32 %sub)

    Inst:   %sub = sub nsw i32 %1, 1

Call:   %call = call i32 @_Z1ai(i32 4)

Call:   %call1 = call i32 @_Z1bi(i32 5)

Call:   %call2 = call i32 @_Z1bi(i32 6)
```